# How to get an exect output from the console

Tags: java, cmd

When I start the command I would like to get the exact output from the console. This is my code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;
try {
    p = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c kotlinc -script " + script.getAbsolutePath());
    p.getOutputStream().close(); // close stdin of child

    InputStream processStdOutput = p.getInputStream();
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(processStdOutput);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        output.setText(output.getText() + line + "\n");
    }

    p.waitFor();
    int code = p.exitValue();
    exitCode.setText("Exit Code: " + Integer.toString(code));

}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    if (p != null)
        p.destroy();
}
```

If the script doesnt have any errors it just displays the output: for example if I just println("test") in my script, the output is "test". But if I have something like that: dasjhdaiushdkjashduisah, the output is empty, but if I start the script from the cmd the output would be: error:
`unresolved reference: dasjhdaiushdkjashduisah(script.kts:1:1) script.kts:1:1: error: unresolved reference: dasjhdaiushdkjashduisah`

So how should I get the exect output?

Comment: This seems like an error. Have you checked ```p.getErrorStream()```?

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know that there is also ErrorStream,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by using the `p.getInputStream()` for the non error output and `p.getErrorStream()` for the output with errors

Comment: Consider using class [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of class `java.lang.Runtime`